# Replace a value on google docs with a value from a google sheets cell

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs

Im trying to import values from a spreadsheet on google sheets to a google doc text so every time i change this value on the sheet it'll be changed on the document.
I tried writing this but it didnt work and im not fully sure of what im writing.

```
  
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("");

var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('page2');
var range = sheet.getRange(1,1); 
var data = range.getValue(A2);

var doc = DocumentApp.openById("")

const body = doc.getBody();
body.replaceText('{{First Name}}', data)
}
```

Comment: From `so every time i change this value on the sheet it'll be changed on the document.`, in your situation, you want to replace the text of the specific position on Google Document every time the cell value is edited. Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 1):

Try it this way:

```
function onMyEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if (sh.getName() == 'page2' && e.range.columnStart == 1 && e.range.rowStart == 1 && e.value) {
    var doc = DocumentApp.openById("")
    const body = doc.getBody();
    body.replaceText('{{First Name}}', e.value)
    doc.saveAndClose();
  }
}
```

You need to create and installable onEdit trigger.  I think you will need it to open a doc file.

Comment: The sheet i have updates automatically with formulas and querys, i needed the doc to only reflect what's on the cell at the time like, the cell is 20, the doc will say ana bought 20, so if that value changes to 21 on the next day i need the doc to also reflect it.